# Newbie in C++. First text game

Tags: c++

I study C ++ and try to create the first game. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void info () {
    int LVL = 1;
    int money = 1000;
    int EXP = 0;
    int work = 200;
    int learn = 15;
    int k = 0;  
}


void menu ()
{
    info ();
    char menu_items;
    cout << "Choose action: " << "\n" << "1. Work" << "\n" << "2. Learn" << endl; 
    cin >> k;

    if (k == 1){
        int money = money + work;
        cout << "U worked (+ "<< money  << " dollars)" << "\n" << endl;
    } if (k == 2) {
        int EXP = EXP + learn;
        cout << "U learned (+ " << EXP << " EXP)" << "\n" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "ERROR" << endl;
    }
}


int main()
{   
    info ();
    while (LVL == 10) {
        cout << "End game!";
    }

    while (LVL != 10) {
    cout << "Your data: " << "\n" << "Money: " << money << "\n" << "EXP: " << EXP << "\n" << "LVL: " << LVL << "\n" << endl;
    menu ();
    }
}
```

Please correct the following: 
1) The cyclic output data after rewrite 
2) Proper cycle add money and experience when choosing one of the following actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Info should probably be a class or struct. You only want to instantiate it once, and persist the values over your calls.

One option might be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct info {
    int lvl = 1;
    int money = 1000;
    int exp = 0;
    const int work = 200;
    const int learn = 15;
};

int main()
{
    info i;
    string k;
    while (i.lvl < 10)
    {
        cout << "Your data: " << "\n" << "Money: " << i.money << "\n" << "EXP: " << i.exp << "\n" << "LVL: " << i.lvl << endl;
        cout << "Choose action: " << "\n" << "1. Work" << "\n" << "2. Learn" << endl;
        cin >> k;
        if (k == "1")
        {
            i.money += i.work;
            cout << "You worked (+ " << i.work << " dollars, now " << i.money << ")" << endl;
        }
        else if (k == "2")
        {
            i.exp += i.learn;
            cout << "You learned (+ " << i.learn << " EXP, now " << i.exp << ")" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "ERROR" << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "You won!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Hmm..can u rewrite my code? I will be very grateful)

Comment: Just did :) It might be buggy, I haven't tested it in the least.

Comment: Wow..ty)
But, "7 15 [Warning] non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]"

Comment: What version of C++ are you working in? Also, I should mention that your question isn't really well-formed; stackoverflow works a bit differently than you might be imagining. I posted a solution in the hope that it will help you ramp up on programming, but typically questions like yours are not answered.

Answer (score 0):

`#include <iostream>`

`#include <string>`

`using namespace std;`

`void menu()`
`{`

```
int money = 1000;
int EXP = 0;
int work = 200;
int learn = 15;
int k = 0;

cout << "Choose action: \n 1. Work \n 2. Learn "<< endl;
    cin >> k;

if (k == 1){
    money =money + work;
    cout << "U worked (+ " << money << " dollars)" << "\n" << endl;
} if (k == 2) {
    EXP = EXP + learn;
    cout << "U learned (+ " << EXP << " EXP)" << "\n" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "ERROR" << endl;
}
```

}

`int main()`

`{`

`int money = 1000;`

`int LVL = 1;`

`int EXP = 0;`

`while (LVL == 10) {`

```
`cout << "End game!"; `
```

`}`

`while (LVL != 10) {`

`cout << "Your data: " << "\n" << "Money: " << money << "\n" << "EXP: " << EXP << "\n" << "LVL: " << LVL << "\n" << endl;`

`menu();`

`}`

`return 0;`
`}`